# How can I get a Range incorporating X rows and Y rows given a starting point in Excel with VSTO & C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an Excel Workbook which has some VSTO-based c# code.

Given a known point:

```
var start = START.get_Address(); // "$A$10"
```

I want to create a range that starts with `$A$10` but incorporates an extra X rows and Y columns.

For example

```
var x = 10;
var y = 5;
```

I want a range that represents `$A$10:$F$20`.

I can do it by combining addresses:

```
var end = ((Excel.Range) START.get_Offset(x, y)).get_Address();

var targetRangeAddress = start + ":" + end;
var newRange = get_Range(targetRangeAddress, System.Type.Missing);
```

However, there must be an easier way. The above is pretty ugly.

Comment: Use Resize() if that exists in VSTO

Comment: @TimWilliams has the correct answer. The `get_Resize()` method is the method you're looking for.

Comment: Tim, that worked great thanks. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it: `var newRange = START.Resize[x, y];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use VBA's `Resize()` or as another commenter pointed out, `get_Resize()` is the VSTO equivalent.

Comment: Reference to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.resize.aspx